# jQuery undefined error HTML5 video tag addEventListener

Tags: jquery, html, html5-video, addeventlistener

I have following jquery code

```
video1=$("#P div video"); alert(video1);
video1.addEventListener('ended',videoEnded,false);
```

and getting following error

TypeError: video1 is undefined

HTML is

```
<div style="position: relative; z-index: 0;" id="P">
    <div style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;z-index:0;">
        <video autoplay="" preload="auto">
            <source type="video/mp4" src="img/f.mp4"></source>
            <source type="video/ogg" src="img/f2.ogv"></source>
        </video>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And did you add jQuery, document.ready, and all the other things needed ?

Comment: yeah jquery lib added andversion is 1.8.3

Comment: does the script code run after DOM has loaded (ie. at end of body or inside a $(window).load/ready call) ?

Comment: script is in head tag within domready